# The relationship between $G_i H / G_{i+1} H$ and $G_i /G_{i+1}$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group, $G_{i+1} \triangleleft G_i \triangleleft G$, $H \triangleleft G$. I need to investigate the relationship between the groups $G_i H / G_{i+1} H$ and $G_i /G_{i+1}$, but so far I can't see how to do it. Any hints?

Comment: It might be useful (as a first step) to look at the basic [isomorphism theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem).  Nothing appears directly applicable, but it might help you determine what intermediate steps to strive for and suggest what the answers might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to preface this answer with the fact that I'm including an extra assumption, as I'm not sure how to answer the problem without it. The assumption is that $G_i \cap H = 1$, and I'll explain why I assume that when I reach that section of the proof.

First, we use the Zassenhaus or [Butterfly Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_lemma) (page 20 of Lang's Algebra provides a proof), which states that, given $A,C \leq G$, $B \triangleleft A$, and $D \triangleleft C$, then $$ \frac{(A \cap C)B}{(A \cap D)B} \cong \frac{(A \cap C)D}{(B \cap C)D}$$

Choosing $A=G_i$, $B=G_{i+1}$, $C=G$, and $D=H$, we have $$ \frac{(G_i \cap G)G_{i+1}}{(G_i \cap H)G_{i+1}} \cong \frac{(G_i \cap G)H}{(G_{i+1} \cap G)H}$$

Since $G_i, G_{i+1} \leq G$ then $G_i \cap G = G_i$ and $G_{i+1} \cap G = G_{i+1}$. We also have $G_i G_{i+1} = G_i$ since $G_{i+1} \leq G_i$. Thus, after all of these simplifications, we have $$ \frac{G_i}{(G_i \cap H)G_{i+1}} \cong \frac{G_i H}{G_{i+1} H}$$

Now, this holds regardless of any conditions on $G_i \cap H$. With the extra assumption that $G_i \cap H = 1$, we have the far prettier $$ \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}} \cong \frac{G_i H}{G_{i+1} H}$$

This, of course, fails dramatically in the case that $G_i \cap H \ne 1$. However, based on the fact that you are specifically looking for a relationship between $G_i / G_{i+1}$ and $G_i H / G_{i+1} H$ and the similarities between these two congruences, I'd hazard a guess that the problem was supposed to stipulate that their intersection is the identity. Feel free to let me know what you think Alexei.

Comment: Actually I'm proving that if $G$ is solvable, then $G/H$ is solvable, it's from page _19_ of Lang's ^_^ So the thing I really need to prove is that $G_i H/ G_{i+1} H$ (or the quotient from a more suitable tower) is abelian whenever $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian.

Comment: Actually, injective homomorphism $G_{i+1} \to (G_i \cap H) G_{i+1}$ induces a surjective homomorphism $\frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}} \to \frac{G_i}{(G_i \cap H) G_{i+1}}$, and using this homomorphism it is easy to prove that the latter is abelian. I only asked for a hint, but still thanks :D

Comment: Oh yeah, I found it. I definitely only read a few pages after the Butterfly Lemma when I was answering this and not one page before, oh well. Also, my brain completely ignored the fact you only asked for a hint, so my bad